# ListView Upload failing Device

Tags: android

Please I have a very good problem here. I'm new to Android and I am trying to develop an android software that uses database and upload it into a List. This worked perfectly well on emulator but when tested on my device it gives an error that my app is not responding, please force to close. Please I will appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: add your code here what you trying to do ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy to answer your question The causes may be many. Surely you need understand the ANR problem, looking [here](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html)

In order to find the cause of problem I can suggest you to try tracking the ANR using this from command prompt:

```
adb shell cat /data/anr/traces.txt
```

that will dump all the appplication not responding traces to the command prompt.